# android.app.RemoteServiceException android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage getting this error in Playconsole

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

App is showing this error in playconsole and it is reporting many crashes without showing at which point it is happening.I am not able to replicate it.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1785)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:205)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6991)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by bugs in the software on some devices. So it can not be solved in the app code. The only realistic solution is to go crashes and ANR on the play developer console and find the problem devices. Then go to device manager on the same developer console and exclude those devices. I have seen that Huawei HUAWEI Y5 causes a lot of these crashes.